# Why Is A UIAlertview is Popping Up When Notification Is Received While App Is Open (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, notifications, push-notification

I have an app built using Cordova.

We have a problem with push notifications and alerts. I thought by default the system would know not to send a UIAlertView if the user has the app open when they get a push notification.

This is not the case, any time the phone is open, and a push notification is recieved, there is a UIAlertview that is appearing for EVERY SINGLE NOTIFICATION.

So for example, if the user posts something, and 20 people do something which sends an event, the app is getting 20 alerts pop ups.

**How can I disable Push Notification Alerts if the app is open?**

Answer (score 0):

Go to AppDelegate+notification.m file in Plugin Folder

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];

if (appState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    // your UIalertview
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The alert still gets displayed (if the message from the server sends an alert flag in the payload). The alert is displayed BEFORE this method is called